# GET request using node/request throwing unexpected "read ECONNRESET"

Tags: node.js, https, postman, node-request

I am getting strange behavior using the request library in node when hitting certain sites.

for a quick context (that has nothing to do with the technical issue): my goal on this project was to read the NASDAQ dividend history for a number of stocks. The histories can be quite long and I'm certainly not going to sit here and read 100 of them manually. An example of one of these pages: https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/msft/dividend-history

On to the technical troubles... I am using node v11.10.0 with the request module to call the page - the simplest possible thing. I have used this library to do other similar tasks and have never had an issue. Here was my very simple script:

```
var request = require("request");
var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/msft/dividend-history',
  headers: 
  { 'Postman-Token': 'e4e9749e-d73e-44b9-994f-9d0522654fb0',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache' } };
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(body);
});
```

Save file as index.js, and run

```
node index.js
```

and that should get the page... except I'm getting an error. The error is:

```
Error: Error: read ECONNRESET
at Request._callback (<localpath>\index.js:8:24)
at self.callback (<localpath>\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:197:13)
at Request.onRequestError (<localpath>\node_modules\request\request.js:881:8)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:197:13)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:397:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:197:13)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
```

So, thinking that I maybe had something wrong, I tried the same request in postman to validate. But Postman had no trouble doing a get request against the same URL above. I thought perhaps there was a certificate issue with the https stuff, but I toggled certificate validation on and off in postman, and it worked regardless of the setting.

[image: works in postman, ta-da!]

Additional note here - my "very simple script" is actually what I pulled from the Postman "code" tab for a Node/Request code block, so I am really baffled that Postman works but Postman's own node codeblock does not.

At this point I don't even care about what I was trying to do originally... I'm just trying to figure out why I am getting different behavior on two seemingly equivalent ways to make a GET request.

Does anyone have insight on what postman has that node is missing in this case?

Comment: I just tried by forging a request with exactly the same header data as the browser's: it works. I removed all data until it doesn't work (I don't see `ECONNRESET`, it just hangs, maybe I killed the process too early?). It appears the site doesn't respond if cookie `ak_bmsc` isn't set. It's normally a very long hash, but it worked for me by simply setting `options.headers.Cookie = 'ak_bmsc=';` (i.e. no value provided).

Comment: Yes for my case it was due to an http header